# Do Car Safety (Colision) Regulations Depend on Max Speed?

Tags: regulations

To what degree is a Car's crash worthiness dependent on max speed? If a car could only reach a max speed of 45 mph, would it require less protective measures than your average car that goes 60+ easily? I am interested particularly in the US and the World Forum for Harmonization of Vehicle Regulations.

Comment: It seems to me that the *other* car could be going any speed.

Comment: It would be the max combined speeds. If you're a grandma going 30 down a road and drunk in the other lane crosses the middle going 70 the force would be approximately the same (different trajectory?) between the two vehicles. If I remember correctly that example may also be the same as one vehicle hitting an immovable wall at 100.

Comment: @DaveTweed I was primarily interested in the possibility of a cheaper, lighter, more fuel efficient car that would need certain driving restrictions to make certain the combined speeds did not exceed 2x max speed. Whether this is practical is another question entirely.

Comment: Similar to a motorcycle?

Comment: @Dopeybob435 More like a car version of a moped. I know there are mopeds with fairings, but I was thinking more of crash safety. I believe there is a company trying to do something similar called elio motors.

Answer (score 3):

You might look up NCAP and ASIL-related documentation.

However, in general,  all vehicles of a given class are required to meet safety standards at a given speed.   It's rather doubtful that any vehicle will be approved as a personal passenger vehicle if it cannot attain highway speeds;  similarly it's unlikely that anyone would bother to require crashworthiness at impact speeds of, say 250 km/h . (for one thing, it's essentially impossible to keep g-forces below lethal levels in the kind of stopping distances involved)